# Cannot see list of drivers in Eclipse (Kepler)

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, eclipse-kepler

I am trying to learn JDBC. The first step is to connect Oracle DB to eclipse. I installed Oracle XE. Now, when I am trying to connect to eclipse, I do not see a list of drivers.

Also, as according to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14545_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.database.doc/html/gettingStarted/files/gettingStarted.html) page, I cannot see Oracle Database Connection. I only see "Oracle"

I also tried opening the eclipse after cleaning (adding -clean in the .ini file) But it didn't work. What am I missing here?

Comment: You only see that option if you installed the appropriate plugin, which you likely didn't. Why can't you just use the default Oracle option?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the JDBC driver from [OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html) and add it to the classpath.